# Error accessing Spark thrift Server

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-1.6, spark-thriftserver

Spark version: 1.6.3

I running Spark thrift server as proxy. But it not running as long as I expected. It always stop when get high load.

This is Error when I access.

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 500 Server Error</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 500</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /jobs/. Reason:
<pre>    Server Error</pre></p><h3>Caused by:</h3><pre>java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
 at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3664)
 at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:207)
 at java.lang.StringBuilder.toString(StringBuilder.java:407)
 at scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder.toString(StringBuilder.scala:427)
 at scala.xml.Node.buildString(Node.scala:161)
 at scala.xml.Node.toString(Node.scala:166)
 at org.apache.spark.ui.JettyUtils$$anonfun$htmlResponderToServlet$1.apply(JettyUtils.scala:55)
 at org.apache.spark.ui.JettyUtils$$anonfun$htmlResponderToServlet$1.apply(JettyUtils.scala:55)
 at org.apache.spark.ui.JettyUtils$$anon$1.doGet(JettyUtils.scala:83)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
 at org.spark-project.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)
 at org.spark-project.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1507)
 at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter.doFilter(AmIpFilter.java:179)
 at org.spark-project.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1478)
 at org.spark-project.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:499)
 at org.spark-project.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
 at org.spark-project.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:427)
 at org.spark-project.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
 at org.spark-project.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
 at org.spark-project.jetty.server.handler.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:301)
 at org.spark-project.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
 at org.spark-project.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
 at org.spark-project.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
 at org.spark-project.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
 at org.spark-project.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:973)
 at org.spark-project.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1035)
 at org.spark-project.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:641)
 at org.spark-project.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:231)
 at org.spark-project.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
 at org.spark-project.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:696)
 at org.spark-project.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:53)
</pre>
<hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><br/>                                                
</body>
</html>
```

I see error is **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space**

But I don't know what memory I need increase:

- Memory of server running SPARK
- Memory of executor configure with SPARK
- other Memory configure...

Update: my SPARK configure

[my SPARK configure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEQZP.png)

Answer (score 0):

The thrift server runs in it's own memory space. You can specify that via the executor memory property.

For example

```
./sbin/start-thriftserver.sh --executor-memory 512m
```

I think [the default is `1g`, as the `spark-env.sh` has](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-1.6/conf/spark-env.sh.template#L41).

Comment: you mean I need increase spark.executor.memory. I update my configure on my post. I use 4G for spark.executor.memory properties

Comment: In HDP, I believe Ambari groups everything under "Spark daemon memory"

Comment: so I will try increase SPARK_DAEMON_MEMORY. But is there any calculation to know my configuration fits my data ?

Comment: Not if you keep reaching the limits... You need to keep increasing until your process stays up. You can try enabling JMX monitoring, but even Java website gives that advice

Comment: I increase memory and spark-thrift server can keep running about two days, then after that it stops and I have to restart the service. It always stops after two days running

Comment: Sounds like the garbage collection isn't working correctly then. Like I said, see if you can get JMX monitoring on the service, then watch the JVM memory

Comment: How I can monitor JMX, any built-in tool or I need install some other tools.

Comment: I don't have any examples, but the documentation is here https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#metrics and most people I've seen use Jconsole (comes with the JDK) to attach to a running JVM to look at data points, but you'll want a graph, and in that case, Grafana with Prometheus seems to be the popular option nowadays

Comment: Maybe something like this, but skipping over the Cassandra stuff https://www.supergloo.com/fieldnotes/spark-performance-monitoring/

Answer (score 0):

Based on the number of nodes in the cluster the Spark thrift Server can be brought up for( e.g., on AWS EMR) you can use with 1 small r3.2xlarge node

```
sudo /usr/lib/spark/sbin/start-thriftserver.sh --driver-memory 10g --verbose --master yarn-client --executor-memory 15g --num-executors 6 --executor-cores 2
```

Also ensure monitoring or cleaning up the Spark History folder -
`hdfs dfs -ls /var/log/spark/apps/` -- on EMR

Queries will be stuck if multiple jobs are in `.inprogress` state in the folder

there is a way to set up automated cleanup of Spark history folder